# How to create custom resources in AWS CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Hi I am trying to create custom resources in aws cdk. I downloaded pip install aws-cdk.custom-resources then trying to create below custom resources.

Below is sample cloud formation resource I created earlier.

```
TagLogGroupFunction:
    Type: "Custom::tagloggroup"
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !ImportValue infra-functions-tag-log-group::TagLogGroupFunctionArn
      LogGroupName: "my log group name"
      LogShipper: "sumo"
      Enable: "true"
```

Can someone help me to create template? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're making a log group which might a bit different, but I found this example. Does it help to answer the question?

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/custom-resource/my-custom-resource.ts

Comment: I didn't find that type in the CloudFormation documentation. What are you trying to do exactly? Tag a log group? Create a custom resource which tags a log group?